# Is it possible to download .swf files which are not embedded

Tags: download, flash

Currently I'm looking for a possibilty to download a .swf file. I need it, to present the page offline in a media-design lesson. The problem is not, that I don't know how to donwload a .swf file. The problem is, that this page got no real .swf file, which is embedded like normal. The page-description just says "object", not "embed". Is there a possibilty to download the file?

Page: http://aquacarpatica.com/#/en
Direct SWF-Link: http://aquacarpatica.com/data/main.swf

Answer (score 0):

Right click your link ( in this very question! ).

Choose Save File As....

Just done this myself and have your SWF file on my local computer.

I appreciate that embedded resources aren't shown as something you can right click and download, but you can create a href link to them in a separate page.

So, create a new HTML file which you can view locally.

Include:-

```
<a href="http://aquacarpatica.com/data/main.swf">Right click me!</a>
```

..in your HTML file.

Open the file, right click the link = job done.  Should work for any static linked content.

Comment: Of cause I can download it this way, but it just relocates me to no page, but "http://aquacarpatica.com/data/main.swf". I have to watch it offline, not online. This works for me just online (tested it). Why?

Comment: That's what happens if you left-click. If you right-click, a menu should pop up and you can select what to do, and one of the options is to download the file.

Comment: Yea, but it downloads a file with 118kb which just refers to the main page of  www.aquacarpatica.com ;)